# Flutter ,Chaquopy example

Tags: python, flutter, chaquopy

Can anyone provide a simple example where we call a function from script.py file in flutter using chaquopy, as the [example provided in pub-dev](https://pub.dev/documentation/chaquopy/latest/) does not show how to call a .py file using chaquopy in flutter, all the examples of chaquopy were for kotlin or java and they dont work for flutter  , even a simple print statement from the python file would suffice.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am the creator of that plugin, you can checkout [this](https://github.com/jaydangar/chaquopy_flutter) public repository for how it works internally. It includes the function calling part that you required for your reference.